# Multiple Requests JQuery in Html Youtube Channel Counter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, api, youtube

I want to make a simple private youtube counter to see Subscribers, Videos and so on and compare them to other Channels. My problem is, I know how to get Infos from 1 Channel but not from multiple.

Code:

```
function info(cid) {
    $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
            part: 'statistics',
            id: cid,
            key: 'Super Secret Key'
        },
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {

                var subs = item.statistics.subscriberCount
                var views = item.statistics.viewCount
                var videos = item.statistics.videoCount
            })
        }
    );
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    window.setInterval("info('UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw')", 1000);
})
```

I uploaded it to [PasteBin](https://pastebin.com/pEbjB7pt), because it somehow didn't format correct here.

I have a function that calls the google API and returns the Channel stats, but How can I  give out the multiple Requests in html?

When I have 3 Channels then it overrides the previous Channel and so on...

Comment: Look at the Pastebin Code, because I didnt know how to paste it here correctly: https://pastebin.com/pEbjB7pt

Answer (score 0):

If you want have more than one counter for each Youtube Channel you want supply, you can still use the code you provided, but I made a few modifications:

- Added a div dedicated to show the info *(in this case, video, subscribers and video counters)* of  the youtube channel.
- Call `info` function and pass the youtube channel id you want get the count information.

In this example, I added three channels:

- PewDiePiew *(it's the channel id you have in your question)*.
- Microsoft HoloLens
- TED Talk

From the mentioned channels, the following code will get:

- Subscribers count
- View count
- Video count

```js
// Please note, this is a youtube api key founded on intenet, use your own Youtube api key.
function info(cid, div_id, channel_name) {
  $.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels", {
      part: 'statistics',
      id: cid,
      key: 'AIzaSyBMdBIAc5VmMNV6M7aCwsKmQH8Yf4ctHmc'
    },
    function(data) {
      $.each(data.items, function(i, item) {
        if (document.getElementById(div_id) != undefined) {
          document.getElementById(div_id).innerHTML = "Channel name: " + channel_name + "<br/>" +
            "item.statistics.subscriberCount: " + item.statistics.subscriberCount + "<br/>" +
            "item.statistics.viewCount: " + item.statistics.viewCount + "<br/>" +
            "item.statistics.videoCount: " + item.statistics.videoCount;
        }
      })
    }
  );
}
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  window.setInterval("info('UC-lHJZR3Gqxm24_Vd_AJ5Yw', 'div_pewdiepiew', 'PewDiePiew')", 1000);
  window.setInterval("info('UCT2rZIAL-zNqeK1OmLLUa6g', 'div_microsoftHoloLens', 'Microsoft HoloLens')", 1000);
  window.setInterval("info('UCAuUUnT6oDeKwE6v1NGQxug', 'div_TEDTalks', 'TED Talks')", 1000);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="div_pewdiepiew">
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="div_microsoftHoloLens">
</div>
<hr/>
<div id="div_TEDTalks">
</div>
```